# What happens when constructor throws on vector.emplace or vector.emplace_back?

Tags: c++, oop, c++11, stl

I have a class which could potentially throw an exception when constructing.
I need many objects of this class, and I am constructing them in a vector with emplace_back. What would happen should the constructor throw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it depends on what constructors are being called.

According to section 23.3.7.5 in the standard, calls to `emplace_back` should have no effect if *custom* constructors throw:

> ```
> template <class... Args> void emplace_back(Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> If an exception is thrown other than by the copy constructor, move
>   constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of T or
>   by any InputIterator operation there are no effects.

Comment: Could you point me to where I could get the C++11 standard?
Seems to be quite useful

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf is the freely-available C++11 working draft, which is pretty close to the official C++11 standard.

Comment: What is meant here by "no effects"? In my program, a normal constructor throws an exception when constructed by `unordered_map.emplace` (which I suppose is specified similarly to `vector.emplace_back`?), and it crashes the program - but without showing an exception was thrown. Is that the specified behavior?

Comment: I'd guess that "no effects" would mean that if you catch the exception and handle it, the container shouldn't change as a result of the whole ordeal. (If your exception is crashing the program despite being caught and handled, that might be another issue?)